# How to change the result addresses order in Google map autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm working on a project using Google map autocomplete control. Please see the code segment below:

```
var options = {
types: ['geocode'], 
componentRestrictions: { country: 'au'}
};
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

However the result addresses order in the autocomplete is different from the one in https://maps.google.com.au/. Btw, I tested my project and maps.google.com.au in the same network.

Is it possible to still use the autocomplete and control the results order by code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method to control the order of the results.

The best chance to get similar results would be to remove the options completely(maps.google.com.au doesn't use these options) and bind the `bounds`-property of the autocomplete to the `bounds` of the map(that's what they are doing).

You may have noticed that you get autocomplete-suggestions related to the viewport of the map on maps.google.com.au

Comment: Thanks Molle, I have tried your suggestion, but no luck. However, your information of this is not achievable is helpful.